# How to use Rundeck workflow global variable inside a Microsoft Teams Notification groovy script?

Tags: groovy, rundeck

I have a Global log key value data filter:
Use this pattern: ^RUNDECK:DATA:(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+)$

Step 1. Output a string that need for next step
echo "RUNDECK:DATA:repo=repository1"

Step 2. Build global variable, using key/value data.
Value: ${data.repo*}
Group: export
Name: repo

Once the job is finished, it will send Microsoft Teams Notification but it did not send any.

Here is the groovy script. I used the workflow global variable for Repository field.

**Repository**: ${execution.export.repo}

/opt/rundeck-plugins/microsoftTeamsIncomingWebhook.groovy

```
import com.dtolabs.rundeck.plugins.notification.NotificationPlugin;
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

rundeckPlugin(NotificationPlugin){

  title="Microsoft Teams Incoming Webhook"

  description="Customized webhook notification script"

  configuration{
    webhook_url title:"MS Teams Incoming Webhook URL"
  }

  def ms_teams_notification = {
    command = [ 'bash', '-c',  "curl -X POST ${configuration.webhook_url} -d '{ \"title\": \"${execution.job.name}\", \"text\": \"[View job in Rundeck](${execution.href})\n\n \n\n **Status**: **${execution.status}** \n\n **Initiated by**: ${execution.user} \n\n **Repository**: ${execution.export.repo}\"}'" ]
    def proc = command.execute()

    proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out,System.err)
    proc.exitValue()==0
  }

  onsuccess ms_teams_notification
  onfailure ms_teams_notification
}
```

Using Rundeck 2.10.8-1

Answer (score 0):

Hi markjeffridelacruz,

I tested your steps in my Rundeck instance, it seems the CURL expression has some invalid parameter, the only change that we did in the groovy file was the third element in the command section, and the file works successfully.

Did you test the curl directly in a terminal?

Did you received any logs when Rundeck tried to send the notification?

Regards.

JB

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: First, you should not address the person, because many people will read the answer. Second, if you have additional question, add a comment to the question. Answers should not start discussions.